# Control edges for lofting

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, workflow

I have 3 edge loops like so:
[image]

I can loft between 2 of them using Bridge Edge Loops or Loft from LoopTools
[image]

I'd like to use the third edge as a guide for the loft, like in most CAD programs. So the end of the loft that not connected to the first 2 edge loops is "guided" along the third edge controlling the shape of the loft.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried selecting them all and using grid fill?

Comment: I have, gives error "select 2 edge loops or a single edge loop...." I've tried connecting the 3 loops but still no luck

Comment: did u ever try animation nodes? or sverchok? i think both can do these things

Comment: I have not... And I've never even heard of "sverchok"... I shall check it out 